# get access token via asp.net Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

According to below references..,

- [Enable OAuth Refresh Tokens in AngularJS App using ASP .NET Web API 2, and Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/)
- [Dissecting the Web API Individual Accounts Template–Part 2: Local Accounts](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/26/dissecting-the-web-api-individual-accounts-templatepart-2-local-accounts/comment-page-1/)

I got below code in order to create access_token.

```
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext.Validated(ticket);
```

But unfortunately, this `Validated(ticket)` method does not return the access_token which is generated auto-magically.

What I want to get is like below code.

```
string _access_token = OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext.Validated(ticket);
System.out.println("Access_token ="+_access_token);
```

Please let me get your suggestion.

Comment: Can looking at the Katana source help?  http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Provider/OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext.cs

Answer (score 1):

You must override method **TokenEndpointResponse** of class OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and get the property **AccessToken** of context.

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        var token = context.AccessToken;
        return base.TokenEndpointResponse(context);
    }
}
```

And of course, you must call your custom provider

```
static Startup()
{
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider(),
    };
}
```